# UserForm ComboBox Populate from dynamic sheet list , add second ComboBox from selection of first ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, combobox, userform

I am looking for some help on populating two (or more) ComboBoxs in a userForm with dynamic data. I have not found a post that can help with this, I do apologies if this is repeat question. I hope this is helpful to others as well.
If you could reply to in a similar style of code and working VBA, it would be appreciated and helpful to others that find this post.

I am sorry, the code function was not working in my favor so the Pseudocode is in text form.

Scenario for this question:

I have different sheets with list information in 3NF (Third Normal Form). The lists will change, adding new lines as needed. List one (ListCustomer) and list two (ListPartNumber). ListCustomer has (currently) less than 10 but may increase with time. ListPartNumber has a reference attribute (column for a customer name/ID) to ListCustomer. ListPartnumber has several hundred entries.

Goal:

Reduce the number of part numbers available to select by first selecting the customer that the part number belongs to.
ComboBoxCustomer populate with a customer Name/ID
ComboBoxPartNumber populate with only Part Numbers that have the attribute of customer Name/ID from the ComboBoxCustomer

Pseudocode: below

```
Sub UserForm_Intialize()

Dim sCustomer (1 to 100) as string

Get list from sheet “Customer List”

Call GetLastRow (ilastrow) ‘ gets the last row in sheet “Customer List”

Z = 0 ‘ counter for assigning array

For irow = 2 to ilastrow  ‘column has a header

Z=z+1

sCustomer(z) = cells(irow,1) ‘ customer Name/ID in column 1

Next irow

‘Populate ComboBoxCustomer with array sCustomer()

End sub

Sub ComboBoxPartNumber ‘(populate with “filtered” data)

dim sCustomer as string ‘assign from entry in ComboBoxCustomer

dim sPartNumber(1 to 10,000) as string ‘ array for part numbers 

‘Get list from sheet “Part Numbers”

Call GetLastRow (ilastrow) ‘ gets the last row in sheet “Part Numbers”

For irow = 2 to ilastrow ‘ row 1 is a header row, go down each row in sheet from row 2 to last row

If cells(irow,2) = sCustomer then   ‘customer Name/ID in column 2

X=x+1

sPartNumber(x) = cells(irow,1)  ‘ part number is in column 1 if the part number has the customer assigned to it load part number

end if

next irow

‘assign array sPartNumber to ComboBoxPartNumber

end Sub
```

Comment: Plenty of existing posts here on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+dependent+comboboxes

Comment: Thank you for providing a link.
The existing Q&A use static data reference, hardcoded or range reference. The data I need to access changes in the number of data points (array will increase and can decrease) on both data sheets.